# In body motor and in lens autofocus motor

Tags: nikon, camera-basics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do camera body motors compare to in-lens motors for focusing?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/10073/how-do-camera-body-motors-compare-to-in-lens-motors-for-focusing)

I am planning to buy a Nikon D5100 camera. However, when I compare it with the Nikon D90, one difference I see is that the Nikon D90 has a in body integral AF motor while the D5100 lacks this and has to use the motor in the lens ? What are the main advantages/disadvantages of having an in body focus motor ? Does this really matter much in the quality of the photos to be clicked ?

Answer (score 2):

Most significant difference is that lenses without built-in focusing motor (all except AF-S and AF-I) can only be used with manual focus when neither body or lens has motor for AF. While newer lenses tend to be AF-S and therefore auto-focusing, there are still many older ones around.

Other differences are already discussed in [another question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/10073/how-do-camera-body-motors-compare-to-in-lens-motors-for-focusing).

Answer (score 1):

You must use lenses with internal focus engine to have auto-focus, which means the Nikkor lenses with letter G (like [this one](http://www.nikonusa.com/Nikon-Products/Product/Camera-Lenses/2183/AF-S-DX-NIKKOR-35mm-f%252F1.8G.html)). If you use older Nikkor models with the letter D (like this [this](http://www.nikonusa.com/Nikon-Products/Product/Camera-Lenses/2137/AF-NIKKOR-50mm-f%252F1.8D.html)) you'll be stuck with manual focus.

Usually lenses with autofocus engine focus faster and quieter than those that use camera's focus engine, but are a bit more expensive and slightly bigger.

Comment: Information in first paragraph is incorrect. G means "gelded" - those lenses do not have aperture ring. D means the lens communicates distance information. Neither letter has anything to do with auto-focusing mechanism. For counterexample, AF 10.5mm f/2.8G will *not* auto-focus on a D5100, and AF-S 17-35mm f/2.8D *will*.

Comment: You're right. What I meant was generally speaking G lenses usually have internal auto-focus engine.

Comment: I'm extremely skeptical that Nikon actually means for the G to stand for "gelded".