# Which DSLR Camera to buy Canon 700D(T5i) vs Nikon D5500?

Tags: dslr

I am a beginner with DSLR.My purpose is nature photography and videos.

I searched over internet and found Canon 700D at much lower price but Nikon D5500 providing much more features. So I liked D5500, but Nikon does not have auto focus motor in body. So does it really matter ? Ans is Nikon D5500 worth of paying few more bucks over Canon 700D or shall I go with Canon 700D ?

So please suggest me. Thanks.

Comment: See 
[How do camera body motors compare to in-lens motors for focusing?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/10073/how-do-camera-body-motors-compare-to-in-lens-motors-for-focusing) to better understand the situation with focus motors.

Comment: See also: [What should I look for when shopping for my first dSLR?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2876/), and [Is there any significant difference between Nikon and Canon?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12746/). BTW, the D5500 is a current model; the [700D is a previous generation model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Canon_EOS_digital_cameras). Apples-to-apples, look at the 750D/760D.

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually I am not seeking for any brand or like that. But I found these 2 models in my budget with good features. Thank you very much for everyone's help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem in Nikon model not having AF motor in its body, as it's a matter of choosing the right glass to fit in. I suggest you to look [here](https://www.graysofwestminster.co.uk/glossary/af_designations.php) and **learn a bit more about AF types**. The choose of the gear is based on the job's needs, assuming both is on your budget. If you can't tell if that `+features` of one model over another are good enough for the cash difference, you should probably get the cheaper one and learn more in the way. Then you can exchange gear in the near future in a more educated decision.